# Efficiently managing similar objects with varying properties and methods

Tags: c#

I am working on a text-based game using C# and WPF. In this game the player can build different structures, probably around 20 unique ones in total when it's all done. Each structure will share some of the same properties, though with different values (such as the cost to build, etc.), and some will have properties and methods unique to themselves. I am trying to figure out the best, most efficient way to implement this.

I have explored using one class for all of them and using a static method with a parameter determining the desired type to generate an instance of the chosen structure, but think that the unique properties and methods some of the structures have would end up making that approach impractical. I could obviously make each different structure its own class and have about 20 of them, all inheriting from an interface containing common members, but I'm hoping that there's a more efficient way to do this that I'm overlooking.

I'm not looking for any code at this point, just concepts that might simplify this process and aid me in the future.

Comment: Create a proper `StructureBase` class which contains all the common logic, then derive from it for each one.

Comment: Using your suggestion, would each type of structure still be its own class since some structures have properties and methods that others don't?

Comment: The only reason not to make a new class for each type of structure is if you intend to do data-driven programming, which is a whole other can of worms

Comment: Having a class for each isn't a problem. I was just looking to see if there were alternate approaches that I could look at. It appears that using a base class or an interface is going to be the way for me to go.

Comment: @JasonD yes, talking about a theoretic object model that doesn't exist does not look like an optimal situation. I would suggest you start coding and the answer to most of your questions will become self-evident as you go.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I certainly appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you look into [Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx) and [Polymorphism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx).

> Inheritance, together with encapsulation and polymorphism, is one of the three primary characteristics (or pillars) of object-oriented programming. Inheritance enables you to create new classes that reuse, extend, and modify the behavior that is defined in other classes. The class whose members are inherited is called the base class, and the class that inherits those members is called the derived class. A derived class can have only one direct base class. However, inheritance is transitive. If ClassC is derived from ClassB, and ClassB is derived from ClassA, ClassC inherits the members declared in ClassB and ClassA.

Specifically I wouldn't use an interface, but an abstract class (Polymorphism) that has the shared code for multiple methods, but mark them as [virtual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx) so that derived(inherited) classes can overwrite the code.  Using only an Interface means that you could be duplicating a lot of code.

Comment: I believe that he already has, considering that he talked about polymorphism in his question.

Comment: I only saw a mention of inheritance using an interface.

Comment: interfaces don't have anything to do with inheritance.  they only do polymorphism

Comment: Either way, it looks like this is the optimal approach to take so I'll go ahead and accept this answer. Thanks for your help.